# If same table is there in a query multiple times do we have to add WITH (NOLOCK) each time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If same table is there in a query multiple times do we have to add `WITH (NOLOCK)` each time? So let's say we have a huge query in which same table maybe referenced multiple times then do we have to add `WITH (NOLOCK)` each time or we can add it once and SQL will ensure that each instance of it is read using `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint.

Comment: Likely the real question is: "Do you really need `WITH (NOLOCK)` at all?"

Comment: Let's say we have a query which is referencing a table twice maybe its a self-join or something like that then do we need to write WITH (NOLOCK) against both the usages of the table or just one and it is understood that both times data has to be read from the table using the hint WITH (NOLOCK)

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)  and 
[Using NOLOCK? Here’s How You’ll Get the Wrong Query Results.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/using-nolock-heres-how-youll-get-the-wrong-query-results/)

Answer (score 2):

I posted a couple of article links in the comments above to help make the point that using `NOLOCK` should be undertaking carefully. But with that said, if you've done your research and understand what you're getting into, there's a far simpler way to achieve it.

Especially when using a query that has many table references, rather than putting `WITH(NOLOCK)` hints on all of them, just set your session's [transaction isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Include a line above your query:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

That's functionally the same as adding a hint to every table in the query, and you can be sure you didn't miss any.

On the other hand, you and your end users might be happier if you

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

Your independent research will tell you why that's true.